# Xamarin Forms - Which is more performant? Padding, Margin, or TranslationX

Tags: performance, user-interface, xamarin.forms

Wondering which of the below items is more performant to do. I would assume that adding an extra layout just for padding would be less performant. Also, is there any negatives, other than performance, to doing simple padding with `TranslationX`?:

```
<Label TranslationX="5"/>
```

Versus

```
<ContentView Padding="5,0,0,0">
    <Label/>
</ContentView>
```

Versus

```
<Label Margin="5"/>
```

*Edit: Was watching the Performance Evolve Session ([link](https://evolve.xamarin.com/session/56e205b0bad314273ca4d817)) and Jason mentioned that using `Label.Margin` is much faster than adding an extra layout to do padding. So now the question becomes, is `Label.Margin` more performant the `Label.TranslationX`. I think I would lean more towards `Margin` since that property is made to do what I want where as `TranslationX` is more geared towards animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Margin` over padding if possible.

`TranslationX` is for animations and something totally different.

You can read the write up of the presentation [here](http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith's-xamarin-forms-performance-tips). Which will improve your Xamarin Forms app performance.